# Select closed request in mysql but getting error means servlet not showing result

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets

I want to select only pending request in servlet

```
String sql = SELECT emailid as request,status as Request_Time,  etr as ETR_Time
               FROM it_Service_ticket
               INNER JOIN it_problem ON
    it_service_ticket.it_problem_id=it_problem.it_problem_id
               WHERE status="closed";

PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Comment: And the error is ?

Comment: Servlet didn't show result

Comment: one suggestion is first try to run the query on your database and see if your getting the results. If you are getting the results then we need to check on the servlet side